# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IAsyncQueryProvider'

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, moq

I am using testing my Identity actions in my .NET Core web application but keep running into problems. I recently found a way to create a mocked usermanager without running into problems with its parameters, but then a new error came to me that I can't find any solutions too: "System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IAsyncQueryProvider'"

Here is my relevant code:

Setting up the mock usermanager:

```
var _userManager = new Mock<FakeUserManager>();
            UserIdentity user1 = new UserIdentity() { Id = UserId1, UserName = "test@gmail.com", Score = 5 };
            UserIdentity user2 = new UserIdentity() { Id = UserId2, UserName = "pragim@gmail.com", Score = 1 };
            UserIdentity user3 = new UserIdentity() { Id = UserId3, UserName = "ajax@gmail.com", Score = 0 };
            UserIdentity user4 = new UserIdentity() { Id = UserId4, UserName = "pim@gmail.com", Score = 4 };
            List<UserIdentity> users = new List<UserIdentity>() { user1, user2, user3, user4 };
            var mock = users.AsQueryable().BuildMock();
            _userManager.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(mock.Object);

var identityRepository = new IdentityRepository(_userManager.Object, null, null);
            _identityService = new IdentityService(identityRepository);
```

FakeUserManager.cs:

```
public class FakeUserManager : UserManager<UserIdentity>
    {
        public FakeUserManager()
            : base(new Mock<IUserStore<UserIdentity>>().Object,
                  new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                  new Mock<IPasswordHasher<UserIdentity>>().Object,
                  new IUserValidator<UserIdentity>[0],
                  new IPasswordValidator<UserIdentity>[0],
                  new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                  new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                  new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                  new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<UserIdentity>>>().Object)
        { }

    }
```

Test method:

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public async Task GetUserAsyncTest()
        {
            //Arrange

            //Act
            var user = await _identityService.GetUserAsync(UserId4);

            //Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("pim@gmail.com", user.UserName);
        }
```

Does anyone know a bypass / solution to my problem?

UPDATE: Stack trace:

```
EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    IdentityRepository.GetUserAsync(Nullable`1 userId) line 55
    IdentityService.GetUserAsync(Nullable`1 id) line 172
    IdentityServiceTests.GetUserAsyncTest() line 102
    ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

and the method GetUserAsync in the repository:

```
        public async Task<UserIdentity> GetUserAsync(Guid? userId)
        {
            return await _userManager.Users.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(userId)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace? It's going to depend one what `GetUserAsync` is doing under the covers; e.g., it could be trying to load a type using the mocked service provider which hasn't been set up.

Comment: @rgvlee I added it to the question, as well as the function GetUserAsync in my repository

Answer (score 4):

Though I am pretty late but after struggling with this error thought should post my bit too.

In my case, a package **MockQueryable.Moq**(https://www.nuget.org/packages/MockQueryable.Moq/)  was being used, upgrading which solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `_users` sequence needs a provider that implements `IAsyncQueryProvider`. Couple of ways you can do it, the following is a mocked implementation.

Firstly, some scaffolding based on your OP:

```
public class UserIdentity : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityRepository
{
    readonly UserManager<UserIdentity> _userManager;

    public IdentityRepository(UserManager<UserIdentity> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<UserIdentity> GetUserAsync(Guid? userId)
    {
        return await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(userId));
    }
}
```

Create your mocked `IAsyncQueryProvider` and add it to your own `IQueryable<UserIdentity>`:

```
var user1 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "foo@bar.com", Score = 1 };
var user2 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "bar@baz.com", Score = 2 };
var user3 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "tony stark", Score = 3000 };
var dataSource = new List<UserIdentity> { user1, user2, user3 }.AsQueryable();

var providerMock = new Mock<IAsyncQueryProvider>();
providerMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync<Task<UserIdentity>>(It.IsAny<Expression>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns((Expression providedExpression, CancellationToken providedCancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(dataSource.Provider.Execute<UserIdentity>(providedExpression)));

var usersMock = new Mock<IQueryable<UserIdentity>>();
usersMock.Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
usersMock.Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(dataSource.Expression);
usersMock.Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(providerMock.Object);

...

userManagerMock.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(() => usersMock.Object);
```

You need a way to set the `IQueryable<T>` provider, the above is just one way you can do it.

If we pull this all together into a working LINQPad sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var user1 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "foo@bar.com", Score = 1 };
    var user2 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "bar@baz.com", Score = 2 };
    var user3 = new UserIdentity() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "tony stark", Score = 3000 };
    var dataSource = new List<UserIdentity> { user1, user2, user3 }.AsQueryable();

    var providerMock = new Mock<IAsyncQueryProvider>();
    providerMock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync<Task<UserIdentity>>(It.IsAny<Expression>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns((Expression providedExpression, CancellationToken providedCancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(dataSource.Provider.Execute<UserIdentity>(providedExpression)));

    var usersMock = new Mock<IQueryable<UserIdentity>>();
    usersMock.Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
    usersMock.Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(dataSource.Expression);
    usersMock.Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(providerMock.Object);

    var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<UserIdentity>>
            (new Mock<IUserStore<UserIdentity>>().Object,
                  new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                  new Mock<IPasswordHasher<UserIdentity>>().Object,
                  new IUserValidator<UserIdentity>[0],
                  new IPasswordValidator<UserIdentity>[0],
                  new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                  new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                  new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                  new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<UserIdentity>>>().Object);

    userManagerMock.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(() => usersMock.Object);

    var identityRepository = new IdentityRepository(userManagerMock.Object);

    var result = identityRepository.GetUserAsync(user2.Id).Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public class UserIdentity : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityRepository
{
    readonly UserManager<UserIdentity> _userManager;

    public IdentityRepository(UserManager<UserIdentity> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<UserIdentity> GetUserAsync(Guid? userId)
    {
        return await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(userId));
    }
}
```

we get the desired result:

[image]

I've left out your `IdentityService` in the above as essentially it's a detail to the answer; you just need to get a working, mocked `UserManager`. For my mock libraries, in particular [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing), I'd use a concrete `IAsyncQueryProvider` rather than a mock; follow the link for an example should you want to go down that path.